# Suggestions for Catpart to VRML Converter

Tags: converters, vrml, catia

I'm looking for a converter from catpart to VRML. Does anyone know a good one?

Answer (score 0):

I never used this add-on (only the regular edition), however the **CAD add-on of [Polytrans](http://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm)** should be able to translate your files:

http://www.okino.com/conv/imp_catia5.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.convertcadfiles.com](https://www.convertcadfiles.com)

This is an online service, thus you don't have to buy and download anything.

You can convert Catia to STL.
Freecad can do the rest of the job (STL to WRML)